# Android Street View - The specified location could not be found

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

Several months ago I integrated Street View thumbnails in my google map application.  Street View has worked perfectly until a few days ago when I started to receive all blank images with the message "The specified location could not be found".

Example URl: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?location=(29.679396,-95.480469)&size=600x400&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Bitmap Image Response: android.graphics.Bitmap@a0701bc

Any ideas why this would start to happen?

Comment: Try to check if your request format is correct? From this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/?csw=1), the sample request format is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=41.403609,2.174448&heading=100&pitch=28&scale=2&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I removed the parentheses around the location and it resolved my problem.  Since it worked with parentheses for many months I can only assume that Google made a change.  The documentation does not show parentheses and I should not have included them in the first place.